# Function enters then before request completed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, request

My async function enters **then** before request is completed. Shouldn't **Then** part of the code executes only after the async function is completed? How to make the function call only when all the function has finished executing?

app.js

```
var request_test = require('./request_test');

baseUrl = "https://github.com";
promiseFunction().then((result)=>{
    console.log("complete")
});

var promiseFunction = async function promiseFunction() {
    request_test.request_test(baseUrl);
}
```

request_test.js

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var request_test = function check(baseUrl) {
    console.log("baseUrl:" + baseUrl)
     var options = {
        url: baseUrl
     };
     request(options, function (error, response, html) {
        if (!error) {
           console.log("no error");
        }else{
        console.log("else js");
        console.log(error);
        }
      });
 }

module.exports = {
    request_test: request_test
};
```

[image: Result]

Comment: `async` has no magic powers to detect completion.  If `request_test.request_test(baseUrl);` is an async function, then it must either return a promise that fulfills when the async operation is done or it must take a callback.  If it returns a promise, then you can return that promise from the parent function and then you can use `.then()` on the parent function.  It appears that you are expecting `promiseFunction()` to magically know when `request_test.request_test(baseUrl);` is done with its async operation.  It doesn't know that.

Comment: Instead, you need to make `request_test.request_test(baseUrl);` return a promise that is linked to its async operation.  Then, you can return that promise from `promiseFunction()` and then `promiseFunction().then()` will work properly.

Comment: Wasn't aware of the need for promise to ensure then works. Added the promise in the request_test module and await in promiseFunction and it works as desired. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `then()` you need to return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). So here is an example of the good old style [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) chain, simply return promise from `request_test` and once you resolve or reject it, `then()` will be called:

```js
promiseFunction().then((result) => {
  console.log("complete");
});

function promiseFunction() {
  return request_test();
}

function request_test() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("no error");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Or maybe use the modern approach - `async` method to `await` call function that returns [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```js
promiseFunction();

async function promiseFunction() {
  await request_test();
  console.log('complete');
}

function request_test() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("no error");
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

Your issue is coming from `var request_test = function check(baseUrl) { ...` inside this function you are not returning [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), you are even returning nothing :)

Comment: Wasn't aware of the need for promise to ensure then works. Added the promise in the request_test module and await in promiseFunction to use the async approach. It works as desired now. Thanks for pointing it out and helpful code.

Comment: I'm glad that it was helpful for you. Good job !

Answer (score 1):

if you are using *async* I would go ahead and use the await/async syntax. Also the package `request` does not return a promise, you have an alternative with `request-promise-native`. The promise should be the return value of your helper function. It could look like this:

```
var request_test = require('./request_test');
var baseUrl = "https://github.com";

var promiseFunction = async function () {
  var result = await request_test.request_test(baseUrl);
  console.log("complete");
}

promiseFunction();
```

and the module:

```
var request = require('request-promise-native');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var request_test = function check(baseUrl) {
  console.log("baseUrl:" + baseUrl)
  var options = {
    url: baseUrl
  };

 return request(options).then(function (error, response, html) {
   if (!error) {
     console.log("no error");
   } else{
     console.log("else js");
     console.log(error);
   }
 });
}

module.exports = {
  request_test: request_test
};
```

Comment: The operative question is what does `request_test.request_test(baseUrl);` return.  Without knowing that, this is just a wild guess.  And, in fact, there's no reason to use `await` because if it does return a promise, that promise can just be returned.  No need for `async` or `await` in that case.  But, probably it doesn't return a promise so that's the real issue here.  Rather than make wild guesses, we should find out what the facts are and then write answers to those facts.  You have enough rep, I would think you would know that.

Comment: well it is a node package, and the assumption was that `request` would return a Promise (which was wrong, as you need to use the `request-promise-native` wrapper instead). Wouldn't think that is such a wild assumption. My point about await/async is that is stylistically better to stick to one type of syntax instead of mixing both.

Comment: Thanks for the package suggestion. Would look into it later. As for the question, I didn't realise that I needed promise for then to work. Added promise and used async approach for the function. I have chosen the previous answer but appreciate your help as well. Thank you